# Issue while installing custom logstash gem filter with logstash 2.3.1

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I was using logstash 1.5.4 and was able to install custom logstash filter received from third party team, now I have updated the logstash from 1.5.4 to 2.3.1 and when I try to install logstash filter it gives me following error:

```
failed: [site1elk01] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/opt/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install /opt/logstash/logstash-filter-abc-1.0.0.gem", "delta": "0:00:11.883231", "end": "2016-04-25 00:38:30.545048", "rc": 1, "start": "2016-04-25 00:38:18.661817", "warnings": []}
stderr: Error Bundler::GemspecError, retrying 1/10
There was a Errno::ENOENT while loading logstash-filter-abc.gemspec:
No such file or directory - git from
  /opt/logstash/vendor/local_gems/bdd6b4de/logstash-filter-abc-1.0.0/logstash-filter-abc.gemspec:14:in `eval_gemspec'
No such file or directory - git from
  /opt/logstash/vendor/local_gems/a945cf06/logstash-filter-abc-1.0.0/logstash-filter-abc.gemspec:14:in `eval_gemspec'
Too many retries, aborting, caused by Bundler::GemspecError
ERROR: Installation Aborted, message: There was a Errno::ENOENT while loading logstash-filter-abc.gemspec:
No such file or directory - git from
  /opt/logstash/vendor/local_gems/a945cf06/logstash-filter-abc-1.0.0/logstash-filter-abc.gemspec:14:in `eval_gemspec'
stdout: Validating /opt/logstash/logstash-filter-abc-1.0.0.gem
Installing logstash-filter-abc
```

Earlier in 1.5.4 I was using below command to install the filter:

```
/opt/logstash/bin/plugin install /opt/logstash/logstash-filter-abc-1.0.0.gem
```

Now after it gave me error to use logstash-plugin from bin folder I am using following:

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install /opt/logstash/logstash-filter-abc-1.0.0.gem
```

Any help here as what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you try the same command with `sudo /opt/logstash...` ?

Comment: Tried with sudo ....Same problem

Comment: If my answer is usefull, feel free to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing a plugin, that is in your local directory not official ones. You should modify,

> "gemfile"

in logstash directory. Thats why you get this error.